# Swift 4.1 Decodable Can't decode nested array with nestedContainer

Tags: ios, swift, codable

Trying to write a simple `Swift 4.1` using Codable to parse `json`.

**I have a `struct` like this:**

```
struct GameCharacter : Codable {
  var name : String
  var weapons : [Weapon]
  enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
    case name
    case weapons
  }

  init(from decoder: Decoder) {
    do {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        let weaponsContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: Weapon.CodingKeys.self, forKey: .weapons)
        self.weapons = try weaponsContainer.decode([Weapon].self, forKey: .weapons)

    } catch let error {
        print("error: \(error)")
        fatalError("error is \(error)")
    }
  }
}
```

**and another like this:**

```
struct Weapon : Codable {    
  var name : String
  enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
    case name
  }

  init(from decoder: Decoder) {
    do {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    } catch let error {
        print("error: \(error)")
        fatalError("error is \(error)")
    }
  }
}
```

**I also have a `struct` for the wrapper like this:**

```
struct Game : Codable {
  var characters : [GameCharacter]
  enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case characters }
}
```

**The json data looks like this:**

```
{ 
  "characters" : [{
    "name" : "Steve",
    "weapons" : [{
      "name" : "toothpick"
    }]
  }]
}
```

**However, I am always getting a typeMismatcherror error:**

> error: typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary,
>   Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue:
>   "characters", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0",
>   intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode
>   Dictionary but found an array instead.", underlyingError:
>   nil))

on this line:

```
let weaponsContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: Weapon.CodingKeys.self, forKey: .weapons)
```

I am not sure what the issue is, as I am clearly (in my view) asking for an array of Weapons, but it thinks I am looking for a dictionary anyway.

Wondering if anyone has any insight as to what I am missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`nestedContainers` is only needed if you want to decode a sub-dictionary or sub-array into the parent struct – for example decode the `weapons` object into the `Game` struct – which is not the case because you declared all nested structs.

To decode the JSON you can omit all CodingKeys and the initializers, take advantage of the magic of `Codable`, this is sufficient:

```
struct Game : Codable {
    let characters : [GameCharacter]
}

struct GameCharacter : Codable {
    let name : String
    let weapons : [Weapon]
}

struct Weapon : Codable {
    let name : String
}
```

and call it

```
do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Game.self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: Thanks @vadian I implemented the initializers early on in response to a different issue.  Guess I did not need to.  Looked like it should have been easy, so I was getting annoyed with added complications that did not seem like they should be necessary.  Glad they weren't!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your struct with following no need for any custom initializers

```
import Foundation

struct Weapon: Codable {
    let characters: [Character]
}

struct Character: Codable {
    let name: String
    let weapons: [WeaponElement]
}

struct WeaponElement: Codable {
    let name: String
}
```

And create

```
extension Weapon {
init(data: Data) throws {
    self = try JSONDecoder().decode(Weapon.self, from: data)
}
```

Now just

```
 let weapon = try Weapon(json)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
let string = """
{
"characters" : [{
    "name" : "Steve",
    "weapons" : [{
    "name" : "toothpick"
        }]
    }]
}
"""

struct GameCharacter: Codable {
    let characters: [Character]
}

struct Character: Codable {
    let name: String
    let weapons: [Weapon]
}

struct Weapon: Codable {
    let name: String
}

let jsonData = string.data(using: .utf8)!
let decodr = JSONDecoder()

let result = try! decodr.decode(GameCharacter.self, from: jsonData)

let weapon = result.characters.flatMap {$0.weapons}

for weaponname in weapon {
    print(weaponname.name) //Output toothpick
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Have the same problem, `JSONDecoder()` only decode the first level of my JSON and then I solve this problem with commented these methods from the body of my class that extended from `Codable`

```
public class Response<T:Codable> : Codable {

    public let data : T?

//commented this two function and my problem Solved <3
//    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
//        case data
//    }
//    required public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
//        data = try T(from: decoder)
//    }


}
```